# How can I get cobertura code coverage for Android MonkeyRunner tests?

Tags: android, code-coverage, cobertura, monkeyrunner, emma

We have been able to get cobertura code coverage for robolectic, using the steps mentioned at https://github.com/stephanenicolas/Quality-Tools-for-Android.

For UI Automation, we are using MonkeyRunner. We have Emma code coverage setup for MonkeyRunner.

Now we would like to aggregate code coverage, but are running into format issue.

Questions:
Is it possible to get Emma code coverage for robolectic? Or
Is it possible to get Cobertura code coverage for MonkeyRunner?

Goal is to have the code coverage reports in the same format so we can merge it.

Thanks!

Comment: monkeyrunner sends events to the emulator/device and obtain some state back, how did you setup Emma code coverage for it?

Comment: Just followed the your blog: http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2011/11/obtaining-code-coverage-of-running.html. Hooked it up to the app such that it will write cc when we exit the app using Back button.

Comment: Any idea on how to get Emma code coverage for robolectric from maven?